# GET IDDate SSIS and SQL using Triggers

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have 2 tables: dimension dim_Calendar_Start and dim_Calendar_End

```
dim_Calendar_start 
(
    id_temp_start, 
    date_start, 
    year, month,
    quarter, 
    week
)

dim_Calendar_END 
(
    id_temp_END, 
    date_end, 
    year, 
    month, 
    quarter, 
    week
)

FACT_TABLE 
(
    BTS date_Start_alarm, 
    date_End_alarm, 
    id_temp_Start, 
    id_temp_End, 
    numOfweek, 
    T, 
    a, 
    pond, 
    t_pond
)
```

I already filled fact table but I just have to fill id_temp-Start and id_temp_End after comparing with fact_table.

date_Start_alarm dim_Calendar_Start.date_Start 
and fact_table.date_end_alarm with dim_Calendar_end.date_end

how can i insert the both id

Comment: "et SQL"? Did you mean "and SQL"?

Comment: i tried this code  but i get error:
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "dbo.FACT_TABLE.DATE_DEBUT_ALRM" could not be bound.

Merge fact_table as target using( select top 1 idDateDeb,PK_Date,
Week_Of_Year
from dbo.dim_date_Debut)as source 
on cast(source.PK_Date as date)=cast(dbo.FACT_TABLE.DATE_DEBUT_ALRM as date)
when matched then
 update set target.ID_TEMP_DEB=source.idDateDeb;

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean in your title when you say "et sql"?

Comment: it's not et sql i have just make mistakes it's and sql

Comment: i want to do triggers when data adding on fact_table id_date_deb and id_date_fin inserted by comparing date from fact_table and calendar and get Id and numberOfWeek